# log4j2 messages from file like Spring MessageSource

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 2.20.0 with spring-boot 1.5.8 under Java 1.8, i'm tring to simplify my software from bloatcode. To log messages I'm currently use this way:

```
#message.properties
message-1=Current time is {0}
message-2=Message for supplier at {0}

@Configuration
public class BeanDefinition {
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("messages.poc");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSourceAccessor getMessageFormatAccessor(MessageSource messageSource) {
        return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }
}

@Component
@Log4j2
public class MessageSourceAccessorRunner implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        Object[] logArgs = {Instant.now()};
        log.info(accessor.getMessage("message-1", logArgs));
    }
}
```

what i'm trying to do is to performing something like this, to save my code from a lot of bloatcode:

```
log.debug("message-2", logArgs);
```

that perform the same effect of

```
log.debug(() -> accessor.getMessage("message-2", logArgs));
```

meaning to logs the message which constructed if the logging level is the DEBUG level, to save performance.

someone can help me to toubleshoot this issue ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does Log4j 2.x interpret the `(String, Object...)` parameters of a logging call is determined by the [`MessageFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MessageFactory.html) used by your logger.

When you create a logger you can pass a `MessageFactory` as second parameter to the `LogManager#getLogger` call (e.g. [`LogManager#getLogger(Class<?>, MessageFactory)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger-java.lang.Class-org.apache.logging.log4j.message.MessageFactory-).

In order to format your messages with a `MessageSource` you need to create:

- a new type of [`Message`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message.html):

  ```java
  public class MessageSourceMessage implements Message {

      private final MessageSource source;
      private final String code;
      private final Object[] args;
      private final Throwable throwable;

      public MessageSourceMessage(MessageSource source, String code, Object[] args) {
          this.source = source;
          this.code = code;
          final int argCount = args.length;
          if (args[argCount - 1] instanceof Throwable) {
              this.args = Arrays.copyOf(args, argCount - 1);
              this.throwable = args[argCount - 1];
          } else {
              this.args = args;
              this.throwable = null;
          }
      }

      @Override
      public String getFormattedMessage() {
          return source.getMessage(code, args, Locale.getDefault());
      }

      @Override
      public String getFormat() {
          return code;
      }

      @Override
      public Object[] getParameters() {
          return args;
      }

      @Override
      public Throwable getThrowable() {
          return throwable;
      }
  }
  ```
- and a matching message factory:

  ```java
  public class MessageSourceMessageFactory extends AbstractMessageFactory {

      private final MessageSource source;

      public MessageSourceMessageFactory(MessageSource source) {
          this.source = source;
      }

      @Override
      public Message newMessage(CharSequence message) {
          return new MessageSourceMessage(source, message.toString(), null);
      }

      @Override
      public Message newMessage(String message) {
          return new MessageSourceMessage(source, message, null);
      }

      @Override
      public Message newMessage(String message, Object... params) {
          return new MessageSourceMessage(source, message, params);
      }
  }
  ```
- then you can use the message factory to instantiate your loggers:

  ```java
  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Example.class,
                                       new MessageSourceMessageFactory(source));
  ```

There are some disadvantages of the example above:

- <s>since "code" gives you no information about the number of parameters, if "code" resolves to "Hello {0} and {1}", a call like</s>

  ```java
  logger.info("code", param0, param1, throwable);
  ```

  <s>will just discard the `throwable` parameter instead of using it as the throwable of the message. You might consider encoding the number of parameters in your code, so that `MessageSourceMessage` can use the first additional parameter as throwable.</s>
- this messagefactory produces temporary objects. You might consider implementing [`ReusableMessage`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/ReusableMessage.html), so that most of the time the same instance of message is used.

**Edit:** since it is not recommended to add `Throwable#toString()` to the log message, I changed the example, so that if the last parameter is an instance of `Throwable`, it is interpreted as the throwable attached to the message.

Comment: interesting, I will implement your solution and feedback you asap !